# How to display numbers under root sign in a TextView?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display numbers under a root sign inside a TextBox or a TextView in java. I can see the root sign, but I can't see the overline.

This is my code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_mathview);
    sqrtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sqrtDisplay);     
    sqrtDisplay.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><strike><o>&radic X + 1</o></strike></html>"));
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? This should be so easy but it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square root symbol can be displayed in android using the unicode : `"\u221a"`

but this won't give you the overline.

There's no such support for symbols to write equations in Android but you can use some of the libraries that are available to achieve that, one of the good options is to use [jqMath](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html) with webview.